# I'm having trouble using multiple UIImageViews in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I put a uiimageview onto my storyboard, in my view controller folder, and when I go to put another image view on the story board, it automatically takes up the whole screen and blocks the other picture. I tried to add the second uiimageview to my view controller folder to set a hierarchy but it won't let me add it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Maybe with some pictures for us to understand what's going on…

Comment: for "it automatically takes up the whole screen and blocks the other picture", it is default behaviour, you have to adjust imageview yourself. for "I tried to add the second uiimageview to my view controller folder to set a hierarchy but it won't let me add it" it is not possible, you must be doing some thing wrong. kindly add some image regarding your problem

Comment: Well you need to use AutoLayout to position / resize your UIImageViews

Comment: select your imageview from your  document outline and resize it using size inspector.

Comment: To all that replied, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me, as for my project, I created a new one in Xcode and everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Select the image view from your Xib and resize it using size inspector. **You can also resize it by dragging the image view and bring one of the corners of the image view visible and resize it by dragging.** Continue the process until you get the exact size and position.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if this case, but if you are using autolayout this is normal, if you don't set constraints to this uiimageview you will encounter strange behavior. So if you set constraints all should work fine